# relation data does not appear in the laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

**relation data does not appear in the laravel view**

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

**> View**

```
              <td>
                @foreach($p->jenis as $a)
                {{ $a->jenis_penyedia }},
                @endforeach
              </td>
```

coba

**> Model Jenis.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Jenis extends Model
{
protected $table="tbl_jenis_penyedia";
protected $fillable=['id_jenis_penyedia','jenis_penyedia'];

public function profile(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile');
}
}
```

**> Model Profile.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
protected $table="tbl_profil_penyedia";
protected $fillable=['id_profil_penyedia','id_jenis_penyedia','nama', 'no_ktp', 'file',  'npwp', 'bank', 'no_rek', 'email', 'no_telp', 'keahlian', 'pengalaman', 'alamat', 'pendidikan'];

    public function jenis(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Jenis');
    }
}
```

Model

**> Controller**

```
        $profile = Profile::all();
         return view('profile/homeprofile',['profile' => $profile]);
```

Controller

no error
only data does not appear

[image]

Comment: maybe it doesn't exist

Comment: Please post your ```jenis_penyedia``` code

Comment: we don't know what `$p->jenis` is

Comment: check again....

Answer (score 2):

Check your db migration file. define this in create_tbl_profil_penyedia_table :
Migrate it.

```
 $table->unsignedInteger('id_jenis_penyedia')->unsigned();
 $table->foreign('id_jenis_penyedia')->references('id_jenis_penyedia')->on('tbl_jenis_penyedia');
```

Edit your Jenis model

```
public function jenis(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Jenis', 'id_jenis_penyedia');
  }
```

According to your controller your view should work like this:

```
 @foreach($profile as $p)
     @foreach($p as $a)
      {{ $a->jenis->jenis_penyedia }},
     @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Check my answer again. I've edited it. 

if you set the relation in your Model class with jenis_penyedia() . it will work

Comment: did u write the migration file correctly ? i mean did u define foreign key and reference on in migration file ?

Comment: without migration

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\user_manage\resources\views\profile\profile.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\user_manage\resources\views\profile\profile.blade.php)

Comment: I meant to ask did u define the relationship correctly in migration file ? wait let me edit my answer

Comment: Check my answer again. Hope it will solve the issue. it seems you didn't define the foreign key and reference on your db table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202350/discussion-between-fahim152-and-el-shaa).